# Default values and validation in ASP RazorPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

My PageModel has a single BindProperty like `?Query=`, whose length should not exceed 1000.  However, I also want this string to always be defined; on initial page load (or if a blank form is submitted), I want to use the default value "*" instead of null or "":

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RazorTestApp.Pages;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Query { get; set; } = "*";

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

I have an equally simple View:

```html
@page
@model IndexModel

<div class="text-center">
    <form method="get">
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <div>
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am having 2 issues with this:

1. Load page with no query string (initial load): the input box correctly displays "*", but I also get a validation error "The Query field is required".
2. Load page with `?Query=` (submit with empty query): the input box does not show the default "*" (shows empty string), and I get the same validation error "The Query field is required".

I am obviously not doing this correctly.  How can I set a default value for Query to be used whenever it is empty/not provided, and have it play nicely with validation?

Comment: `[Display(Name = "Query")] public string Query {get; set;} = '*';` or try to add `[DefaultValue(true)]`. See whether it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the validations on my side.

Below is my model:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true), Required, StringLength(1000)]
        
public string Rating { get; set; } = "*";
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Movie.Rating" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="Movie.Rating" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

On my side, I could see that `*` is added to the input field and if I remove it and submit the form then I get the validation message.

For testing purposes, I would suggest you make a test with the `<form method="post">`. If the issue persists then creating a new model and view and trying to test it separately may help to narrow down the issue.